# Fail when install Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, centos

I use this command to install Rails.

```
 sudo gem install rails -V
```

Then I got this error message. No ideas about the reason...

```
[root@li608-165 ~]# sudo gem install rails -V
HEAD https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=rails
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=actionmailer,actionpack,actionview,activemodel,activerecord,a                                                     ctivesupport,bundler,railties,sprockets-rails
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=arel,builder,erubis,i18n,json,mail,minitest,rack,rack-test,ra                                                     ke,sprockets,thor,thread_safe,tzinfo
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=hike,mime-types,multi_json,tilt,treetop
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=polyglot,polyglot
200 OK
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/.gitignore
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/.travis.yml
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/CHANGES
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/COPYING
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/COPYING-json-jruby
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/GPL
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/Gemfile
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/README-json-jruby.markdown
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/README.rdoc
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/Rakefile
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/TODO
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/VERSION
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/data/example.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/data/index.html
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/data/prototype.js
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/diagrams/.keep
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/fbuffer/fbuffer.h
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/depend
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/extconf.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/generator.c
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/generator.h
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/parser/depend
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/parser/extconf.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/parser/parser.c
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/parser/parser.h
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/parser/parser.rl
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/install.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/java/src/json/ext/ByteListTranscoder.java
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/java/src/json/ext/Generator.java
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/java/src/json/ext/GeneratorMethods.java
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/java/src/json/ext/GeneratorService.java
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/java/src/json/ext/GeneratorState.java
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/java/src/json/ext/OptionsReader.java
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/java/src/json/ext/Parser.java
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/java/src/json/ext/Parser.rl
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/java/src/json/ext/ParserService.java
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/java/src/json/ext/RuntimeInfo.java
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/java/src/json/ext/StringDecoder.java
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/java/src/json/ext/StringEncoder.java
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/java/src/json/ext/Utils.java
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/json-java.gemspec
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/json.gemspec
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/json_pure.gemspec
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/add/bigdecimal.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/add/complex.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/add/core.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/add/date.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/add/date_time.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/add/exception.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/add/ostruct.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/add/range.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/add/rational.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/add/regexp.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/add/struct.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/add/symbol.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/add/time.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext/.keep
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/generic_object.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/pure.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/pure/generator.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/pure/parser.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/version.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail1.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail10.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail11.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail12.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail13.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail14.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail18.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail19.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail2.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail20.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail21.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail22.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail23.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail24.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail25.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail27.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail28.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail3.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail4.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail5.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail6.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail7.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail8.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/fail9.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/pass1.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/pass15.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/pass16.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/pass17.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/pass2.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/pass26.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/fixtures/pass3.json
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/setup_variant.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json_addition.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json_encoding.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json_fixtures.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json_generate.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json_generic_object.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json_string_matching.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json_unicode.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tools/fuzz.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tools/server.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json_addition.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json_encoding.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json_fixtures.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json_generate.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json_generic_object.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json_string_matching.rb
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/tests/test_json_unicode.rb
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    Building has failed. See above output for more information on the failure.
extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/extensions/x86_64-linux/1.8/json-1.8.1/gem_make.out
```

System: CentOS 6.5 
Ruby: 1.8.7

Comment: Are you using RVM, the Ruby version manager? It will let you switch between Ruby versions. And it will install the newest Ruby version 2.1.2. It's best to install in your user environment, not at the system level (so do not use sudo). Here's my article [Install Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu Linux](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-ubuntu.html) which should be helpful for CentOS, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look some piece of log

> can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h

This mean you have not `ruby-devel`
install `ruby-devel`
on `CentOS`:

```
sudo yum install ruby-devel
```

Comment: Thanks! However, after I install ruby-devel, and relaunch the  sudo gem install rails -V.... There is a new error: 
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.

But I use the RVM LIST to show the version of the Ruby:

[root@li608-165 ~]# rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.9.3-p547 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

Comment: No ideas about the reason... I think the Ruby version is OK for the rails installation...

Comment: Install rails without sudo or must be problem. Set ruby version on rvm `rvm use 1.9.3`